# Use Tee-Object with redirecting

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to run this command and [redirect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) all the output to Windows as well as a log file.

```
powershell "C:\backup\backup.bat *>&1 | tee log.txt"
```

so when I run the command I can see the output and also save it in a file, but I am getting this error:

```
Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pa
ss ampersand as a string.
At line:1 char:25
+ C:\backup\backup.bat *>& <<<< 1 | tee log.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Comment: Are you using at least powershell version 3.0 ?

Comment: @CB. no it's version 2.0

Comment: I'm sorry but the redirect you try to use starts only from 3.0 version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the output of .bat file execution to the console as well as to file, use:

```
powershell "& 'C:\backup\backup.bat' *>&1  | Tee-Object -FilePath 'log.txt'"
```

There's a good post, [PowerShell and external commands done right](https://web.archive.org/web/20180317092333/http://edgylogic.com:80/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/), which explains how to start external command. After that simply apply redirection as in the article you linked.

Comment: If i run your command, still i get same error, anything is missing?

Comment: @MoHradA This because this kind of redirection works only from powershell version 3.0.

Comment: @CB. Thanks, is there any other way that be compatible with version 2.0? and if you check the link i provided it wrote like : `Applies To: Windows PowerShell 2.0, Windows PowerShell 3.0`

Comment: @MoHradA Must be an error. In 2.0 redirection can only use `>`.

Answer (score 4):

Redirection of streams other than `Success` and `Error` (AKA `STDOUT` and `STDERR`) isn't supported prior to PowerShell v3, as @CB. mentioned in comments. In PowerShell v2 you can only merge the Error stream:

```
powershell "C:\backup\backup.bat 2>&1 | tee log.txt"
```